# preg_replace is not work correctly with UTF-8 chars?

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-replace

i am using this function to replace bad words from phrases,
but it works good with english letters except UTF-8 chars.

i found that `\b` boundary is not working properly with utf-8 chars.
are there any alternative method to do this ?

i had to add '\b' as i need to replace the exact word only.
as a example: dont want to replace `popo_one` with `p***o` i need only to replace `popo` with `p***o`. hope it is clear to understand.

```
public function wordfilter($phrase) {
    $filter = array('/popo\b/i','/blabla\b/i'); 
    $replace = array('p***o','b***a'); 
    $newphrase = preg_replace($filter, $replace, $phrase); 
return $newphrase;
}
```

any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\b` (a word boundary) is the limit between a character from the `\w` character class and an other character or the limit of the string (begining or end).

By default `\w` contains only `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, but if you use the u modifier the `\w` character class will contain all unicode letters and digits (and will be equivalent to `[\p{L}\p{N}_]`). So with this modifier the meaning of `\b` will change too.

The u modifier has a second effect. With it, the pattern and the subject string are no more treated as ascii strings, but as utf8 strings.

The u modifier is a combination of two directives: `(*UCP)` that changes the meaning of the shorthand character classes (`\w`, `\d`, `\s`...) and `(*UTF8)` that makes pattern and subject strings to be read as utf8 strings. These directives can be placed directly in the pattern at the very begining instead of using the u modifier.

Comment: it works fine, but not at all. it has some errors with utf-8 chars, as example when i try to search and replace this `'/මම\b/u'` it also replace this `මමේ` which is totally unexpected. any ideas pls ?

Comment: @Milan: It's normal, these characters are letters (Sinhala language spoken in Sri Lanka).

Comment: Oky Thanks @Casimir, Yes it is Sinhala :)